# How to "Linq to DataTable" using Own DataTable Class

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatable

How can I put whatever is coming out of this linq query to my own DataTable Class?

```
public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    public MyDataTable()
    {
        this.Columns.Add("ColumnName1");
        this.Columns.Add("ColumnName2");
        this.Columns.Add("ColumnName3");
        this.Columns.Add("ColumnName4");
    }
}
```

My linq query:

```
MasterDataTable
.AsEnumerable()
.Where(rr =>
            rr.Field<string>("ColumnName1") == SelectedValue1 &&
            rr.Field<string>("ColumnName2") == SelectedValue2 &&
            rr.Field<string>("ColumnName3") == SelectedValue3 &&
            rr.Field<string>("ColumnName4") == SelectedValue4)
).Select(rr => rr);
```

I have tried this but it I am warned that I cannot convert an EnumerableRowCollection to MyDataTable

```
MyDataTable dt = MasterDataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(rr =>
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName1") == SelectedValue1 &&
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName2") == SelectedValue2 &&
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName3") == SelectedValue3 &&
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName4") == SelectedValue4)
    ).Select(rr => rr);
```

So then I tried to get it all in an EnumerableRowCollection but here I am getting "Embeded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement"

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> selection = ConfigurationDataTable
.AsEnumerable()
.Where(rr =>
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName1") == SelectedValue1 &&
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName2") == SelectedValue2 &&
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName3") == SelectedValue3 &&
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName4") == SelectedValue4)
).Select(rr => rr);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `MasterDataTable` have the same columns as `MyDataTable`, or are there other columns not included in `MyDataTable`?  And if so why do you feel the need to create a custom class for `MyDataTable`?

Comment: @pwilcox, yes, MasterDataTable is actually just an instance of MyDataTable containing all data. As for your second question: I was actually thinking about the same thing. In essence I am not really doing anything special. I guess I am can just use the native DataTable class.

Answer (score 0):

I threw the custom class out and just used the native DataTable class for both datatables. This seems to do the trick.

```
DataTable dt = MasterDataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(rr =>
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName1") == SelectedValue1 &&
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName2") == SelectedValue2 &&
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName3") == SelectedValue3 &&
                rr.Field<string>("ColumnName4") == SelectedValue4)
    ).Select(rr => rr)
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.  By the way, you can get rid of the use of `Select` entirely.